# Java VowelAnalyst questions

Tags: java

Im very new to java and I actually have no idea what i am doing.  I have this assignment Design and implement an application that reads a string  from the user, then determines and prints how many of each lowercase vowel (a, e, i, o, and u) appear in the entire string . Have a separate counter for each vowel. Also count and print the number of nonvowel characters .

SPECIFICATION OF PROMPTS, LABELS AND OUTPUT : Your code should use the prompt "enter string : ". After the input is read, there are six lines of output , each starting with a different label: "a: ", "e: ", "i: ", "o: ", "u: ", "other: " in that order. After each label is the required count.

For example: if "aardvark heebie jeebies" were read in, the output  would be:
a: 3
e: 6
i: 2
o: 0
u: 0
other: 12

What I have so far is this.  Can someone please help me?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class VowelAnalyst
{
//************************************************************
//Count the number of vowels
//************************************************************

public static void main (String[]args)

{
    String userString;
    int a=0, e=0, i=0, o=0, u=0, other=0;
    char vowels;

    Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);

    System.out.println("enter sentence: ");
    userString = scan.nextLine();

    for (int count=0; count < userString.length; count++)
    {
        vowels = userString.charAt(count);

        switch (vowels)
        {
        case 'a':
            a++;
            break;
        case 'e':
            e++;
            break;
        case 'i':
            i++;
            break;
        case 'o':
            o++;
            break;
        case 'u':
            u++;
            break;
        default:
            other++;
        }

    }
    System.out.println ("a: " + a);
    System.out.println ("e: " + e);
    System.out.println ("i: " + i);
    System.out.println ("o: " + o);
    System.out.println ("u: " + u);
    System.out.println ("other " + other);
}
}
```

Comment: Is there anything wrong with your program?

Comment: Yes should have mentioned that.  It wont compile. VowelAnalyst.java:26: error: cannot find symbol
                for (int count=0; count < userString.length; count++)

Comment: In your `for` loop, `userString.length` should be `userString.length()`. You are missing parentheses. The compilation error should be easy to point out what is wrong here.

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
for (int count=0; count < userString.length; count++)
```

to:

```
for (int count=0; count < userString.length(); count++)
```

With `Strings`, their length is not a property, it is a method call, which is why you need `length()` and not just `length` (you might be getting confused with `array.length`, where you don't need the brackets).

Comment: If this was helpful, could you click the green check mark?  Intangible internet reputation makes my day :)